# Simplifying the explanation of a low-entropy Big Bang

Tags: entropy, big-bang

The claim that the young universe was in a low-entropy state seems at odds with

- maximal entropy being thermal equilibrium, and
- the young universe being in thermal equilibrium.

I've looked at [some](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18702/why-was-the-universe-in-a-extraordinarily-low-entropy-state-right-after-the-big) [other](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4201/why-does-the-low-entropy-at-the-big-bang-require-an-explanation-cosmological-a) answers and they're too technical for me, but I think I've understood the reason to be basically this:

"Entropy was lower because the universe was smaller."

Is this right?

Comment: Considering the cooling was enabled by the expansion of the universe, I think there's a good case for it.

Comment: Because place names are capitalized in English, you're limiting your question to cosmological models that assume (as Roger Penrose & many other physicists do) that there is only a single universe in space.  That's fine, but, seeing that you may not have accepted either of the offered answers, you might draw in a larger number of them by capitalizing "universe" in your question:  That might bring responses from proponents of a "multiverse".

Answer (score 2):

> Is this right?

No.  I think you've arrived at this because you're not considering the gravitational degrees of freedom.  Sheldon Goldstein puts it this way:

> [T]he attractive nature of the gravitational interaction is such that
>   gravitating matter tends to clump, **clumped states having larger
>   entropy**. . . . For an ordinary gas, increasing entropy tends to make
>   the distribution more uniform. For a system of gravitating bodies the
>   reverse is true. High entropy is achieved by gravitational clumping —
>   and the highest of all, by collapse to a black hole.

So, *gravitationally speaking*, the young universe had very low entropy because the distribution of mass-energy was nearly uniform rather than clumped.

Now, the question of *why* this was the case is much more difficult to answer.

Comment: Can you cite the source, please? Intuitively I would expect clumped states to have LESS entropy, what about gravity makes this the reverse of the non-gravitational case? (And aren't all cases gravitational?) Can we derive this result, or is it an axiom we've inserted in order to preserve the doctrine of always-increasing-entropy?

Comment: This is basically right, but I believe there are also arguments to the effect that a maximum-entropy state would have a lot of energy in the form of gravitational waves. Unfortunately I can't find a reference, but this talk may be helpful: http://www.newton.ac.uk/webseminars/pg+ws/2005/gmr/gmrw04/1107/penrose/

Comment: @spraff: Here is a reference that supports the answer, although it doesn't discuss gravitational waves: http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0507094

Answer (score -5):

At the beginning there was a single waveform expanding to the present , very high temperature /energy, and no space ie. one single wave state- low entrophy.

Comment: -1 Your answer makes a statement without any supporting evidence or links or details.